# Oracle Forms 11g R2 connect to Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, installation, tnsnames

Thank in advance!

I have 64bit Windows 7 with installed Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit.

I installed Oracle WebLogic 10.3.6 how it described [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=as1111&id=WLSIG199). But it's install 32bit jdk1.6 with it, I couldn't uncheck it and I don't know why:

[image]

After this, when I had tried to install Oracle Forms 11g R2, on the 5th step it thrown error:

> *"INST-07408: Unable to install or configure the product on a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit machine"*

I've been thinking about it for long time, but the best thing I did it just spoof 32bit jdk1.6 on 64bit jdk1.7 right in folder with 32bit jdk1.6. It worked for me and I was able to install Oracle Forms 11g.

After this I copied the tnsnames.ora from

> *'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN'*

to

> *'C:\oraclexe\Middleware\asinst_3\config'* (yeah, it's already 3rd instance)

After this I run Oracle Forms and trying to connect (system, root), but I receive the error

> *'ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified'*

But I can connect from sqlplus (system, root), which I run from

> *'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\'*

Also I can connect from Sql Developer.

And sqlplus from

> *'C:\oraclexe\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1\BIN\'*

throw error

> *'Message file UTILITY_MSG\spw.msb not found!'*

I'm trying to solve this problem for the second straight night!! Help me please!:)

Comment: Have you set TNS_ADMIN environment variable?

Comment: @JSapkota, I am tried to do it in both ways: set environment variable **TNS_ADMIN** to *'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN'* and in registry **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_OH836589237** there is TNS_ADMIN that setted to *'C:\oraclexe\Middleware\asinst_3\config'*, I tried to replace it with *'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN'*. But it's still not working.

Comment: For the first I installed Oracle Forms 12c and it's just didn't start with error *'FRM-10039: Unable to start up the Form Builder'*, and I couldn't find how to remove it. After I installed Oracle Forms 11g the Oracle Forms 12c became able to start without errors, but it cannot connect to database too.